# How to run specific java code on Tomcat start or on application deploy?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tomcat auto start servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785769/tomcat-auto-start-servlet)
>   [How do I load a java class (not a servlet) when the tomcat server starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175726/how-do-i-load-a-java-class-not-a-servlet-when-the-tomcat-server-starts)

I have web application running on Tomcat server. I want to run specific code in my application once when Tomcat starts or when this application is deployed. How can I achieve it? Thanks

Comment: You are looking for something called "ServletContextListener", it has methods you need.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-special-auto-start-servlet-to-initialize-on-startup-and-share-application

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to implement ServletContextListner interface and write the code in it that you want to execute on tomcat start up.

Here is a brief description about it.

ServletContextListner is inside javax.servlet package.

Here is a brief code on how to do it.

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    //Notification that the servlet context is about to be shut down.   
  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    // do all the tasks that you need to perform just after the server starts

    //Notification that the web application initialization process is starting
  }

}
```

And you need configure it in your deployment descriptor web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        mypackage.MyServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Look into the @WebListener annotation also.

Comment: I needed this and it works. There is also the "load-on-startup" way of doing this. My problem is that both methods initialize the class twice. Any idea? I saw this issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301088/tomcat-servlet-init-called-twice-upon-startup. I just cant understand what to do. Not very familiar with Java.

Comment: Thank you it very useful

Comment: What if my `<listener-class>` is `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` ? Which method will my tomcat server recall first? I mean, which is the entrypoint of my application?