# Using Tomcat to debug in Intellij Idea creates two deployments of Web App

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I am developing a Java Web App in Intellij Idea and currently I am re-writing some of our server jobs to make them more customizable.

The problem I have come across is that when I debug the War file using Idea, I seem to get multiple instances of my Scheduler Servlet running. This leads me to get an 'out of heap space' error. I need to run in Intellij so that I can debug and check variables as my server is running.

This problem does not occur when I run Tomcat straight from the command line.

I've placed a line that divides by zero in my servlet's init method in order to get a stack trace to see where the servlets are being initialized from and here are the results:

First Exception:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at com.visibleequity.servlets.SchedulerContextServlet.init(SchedulerContextServlet.java:25)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1114)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1673)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Second One:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at com.visibleequity.servlets.SchedulerContextServlet.init(SchedulerContextServlet.java:25)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've spent a lot of time reading on the Intellij Support Forum but haven't been able to find a solution that seems to work. I think it has something to do with Tomcat autodeploying from webapps as well as from server.xml (as per [Servlet Init called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301088/tomcat-servlet-init-called-twice-upon-startup)).

Any help or insignt into how I can prevent this problem would be much appreciated. If you need me to post any additional files or information please let me know in the comments.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was with the default startup script. By default intellij was running 'catalina.bat' run. When I changed the command to 'catalina.bat start' the problem went away. Hope this can help anyone else that encounters this problem.